# XSLT attribute based on value in Lookup Table created dynamically in XSLT over multiple XML input files

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I need to take a value dynamically created by the position in a lookup table and assign it to an element created in the same transform, after traversing multiple files.  I have a "manifest" xml file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<files>
    <file>file1.xml</file>
    <file>file2.xml</file>
</files>
```

File 1 and File 2 are as follows:

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <Name>Schwinn Bicycle</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere</Location>
            <Contact>Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
   </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Huffy Bicycle</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Other Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere Else</Location>
            <Contact>Another Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
   </Product>
</ProductList>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <Name>Expensive Bicycle Brand</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Yet Another Store</Name>
            <Location>Whole New Place</Location>
            <Contact>Completely Different Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
   </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Harley Davidson</Name>
        <Type>Motorcycle</Type>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Other Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere Else</Location>
            <Contact>Another Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
   </Product>
</ProductList>
```

Now what I need is for the file XML output to be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductList>
    <Stores>
        <Store id="1" Name="Some Store">Phone Number</Store>
        <Store id="2" Name="Some Other Store">Another Phone Number</Store>
        <Store id="3" Name="Yet Another Store">Completely Different Phone Number</Store>
    </Stores>
    <Products>
        <Product>
            <Name>Huffy Bicycle</Name>
            <StoreContact contactId="2"/>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Schwinn Bicycle</Name>
            <StoreContact contactId="1"/>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Expensive Bicycle Brand</Name>
            <StoreContact contactId="3"/>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <Name>Harly Davidson</Name>
            <StoreContact contactId="2"/>
        </Product>
    </Products>
```

So, to sum it up, I am going through the files and getting the contact information out and using their position to make the lookup table at the top for the resulting XML.  I then create the product elements for the output and need to somehow get the id that was assigned when I created the lookup table.  I need to use pure XSLT 1.0.

**Edit:**  The Id in the lookup table must be an integer value.

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="document(files/file)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="store_contacts" select="document(files/file)/ProductList/Product/Store/Contact"/>

    <xsl:template name="ProductList">
        <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Product"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="Contacts">
        <xsl:element name="contacts">
            <xsl:for-each select="$store_contacts">
                <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($store_contacts[normalize-space(Contact)=normalize-space(current()/Contact)][1])">
                    <xsl:element name="Store">
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Contact)"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="ProductList">
            <xsl:element name="Stores">
                <xsl:call-template name="Contacts"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="Products">
                <xsl:call-template name="ProductList"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Product">
        <xsl:element name="StoreContact">
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="contactId">1
                <!-- lookup value from the table created from all of the files, using the value 1 until I can figure out how to set the correct value -->
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I have tried to find something similar but haven't found any questions on the subject when the op was trying to perform the function while iterating over multiple files.

Comment: Mark_Eng, The currently accepted answer relies on implementation details of some XSLT processors -- that they use hexadecimal numbers as values of the `generate-id()` function. This is unreliable and other XSLT processors may not produce hexadecimal values. See in my answer a correct solution that produces plain integers, as you asked in your question. I also don't make the unreliable assumption that the `Contact` value identifies a store -- instead I use the full tuple of all store's children as the data that identifies that store. Needless to say, I like your question and just voted it up.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer to Dimitres.  In my case both answers did work, but Dimitres was more acceptable.  In my case, the use of the full tuple wasn't necessary (the whole store/contact thing was just an example so that I could use it for the company that I work for, without exposing anything proprietary).  In the case of both answers, it was the concept that I was after.  And in both cases, I very much appreciate the help, if I could select both as accepted answers I would.

Comment: Mark_Eng, You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a complete solution that produces meaningful integer Ids**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAllDocs" select="document(/*/*)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vAllStores" select="$vAllDocs/*/*/Store"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vPositionsOfDistinct">
   <xsl:for-each select="$vAllStores">
     <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="."/>
     <xsl:if test=
      "generate-id() 
     = generate-id($vAllStores[concat(Name,'|',Location,'|',Contact) 
                             = concat($vCur/Name,'|',$vCur/Location,'|',$vCur/Contact)]
                                [1])">
       <xsl:value-of select="concat('|', position())"/>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vDistinctStores" select=
 "$vAllStores[contains($vPositionsOfDistinct, concat('|',position(),'|'))]"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ProductList>
      <Stores>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vAllStores" mode="distinct"/>
      </Stores>
      <Products><xsl:apply-templates select="$vAllDocs/*/Product"/></Products>
    </ProductList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Store" mode="distinct">
    <xsl:if test="contains($vPositionsOfDistinct, concat('|',position(),'|'))">
      <Store id="{position()}" Name="{Name}"><xsl:value-of select="Contact"/></Store>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Product">
     <xsl:variable name="vCur" select="Store"/>
     <xsl:variable name="vPos">
       <xsl:for-each select="$vAllStores">
             <xsl:if test=
                "contains($vPositionsOfDistinct, concat('|',position(),'|'))
               and
                 concat(Name,'|',Location,'|',Contact) 
               = concat($vCur/Name,'|', $vCur/Location,'|', $vCur/Contact)
                ">
               <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
             </xsl:if>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>

   <Product>
     <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
     <StoreContact contactId="{$vPos}"/>
   </Product>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<files>
    <file>afile1.xml</file>
    <file>afile2.xml</file>
</files>
```

**and on the provided two XML files** (two products reordered to show the more interesting case when the resulting store ids are not consecutive integers):

*afile1.xml*:

```
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <Name>Schwinn Bicycle</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere</Location>
            <Contact>Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Huffy Bicycle</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Other Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere Else</Location>
            <Contact>Another Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

*afile2.xml*:

```
<ProductList>
    <Product>
        <Name>Expensive Bicycle Brand</Name>
        <Type>Bicycle</Type>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Some Other Store</Name>
            <Location>Somewhere Else</Location>
            <Contact>Another Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Harley Davidson</Name>
        <Type>Motorcycle</Type>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Store>
            <Name>Yet Another Store</Name>
            <Location>Whole New Place</Location>
            <Contact>Completely Different Phone Number</Contact>
        </Store>
    </Product>
</ProductList>
```

**Then the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ProductList>
   <Stores>
      <Store id="1" Name="Some Store">Phone Number</Store>
      <Store id="2" Name="Some Other Store">Another Phone Number</Store>
      <Store id="4" Name="Yet Another Store">Completely Different Phone Number</Store>
   </Stores>
   <Products>
      <Product>
         <Name>Schwinn Bicycle</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="1"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Huffy Bicycle</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="2"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Expensive Bicycle Brand</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="2"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Harley Davidson</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="4"/>
      </Product>
   </Products>
</ProductList>
```

Comment: Changed this to the correct answer.  Both answers worked, but in my instance, this answer better suited my needs.  Thanks Dimitre.

Answer (score 2):

I understand from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353828/merging-data-from-multiple-xml-files-without-duplicates-using-xslt) that you cannot use the `node-set()` extension function - which makes this very difficult.

I would suggest that, instead of position, you use the unique ids generated by the `generate-id()` function to link products to their stores.

The following stylesheet uses [the method proposed by G. Ken Holman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18958901/3016153) to produce a list of distinct stores gathered from multiple files. We then use the same principle to retrieve the unique id of each product's store:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="document(files/file)"/>
<xsl:variable name="stores" select="$input-docs/ProductList/Product/Store"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <ProductList>
        <Stores>
            <xsl:for-each select="$stores">
                <xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id($stores[Contact=current()/Contact][1])">
                    <Store id="{generate-id()}" Name="{Name}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Contact"/>
                    </Store>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </Stores>
        <Products>
            <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs/ProductList/Product">
                <Product>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                    <StoreContact contactId="{generate-id($stores[Contact=current()/Store/Contact][1])}"/>
                </Product>          
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </Products>
    </ProductList>      
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The actual result can vary slightly according to the processor - here's an example produced by Saxon 6.5:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductList>
   <Stores>
      <Store id="d1e14" Name="Some Store">Phone Number</Store>
      <Store id="d1e38" Name="Some Other Store">Another Phone Number</Store>
      <Store id="d2e14" Name="Yet Another Store">Completely Different Phone Number</Store>
   </Stores>
   <Products>
      <Product>
         <Name>Schwinn Bicycle</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="d1e14"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Huffy Bicycle</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="d1e38"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Expensive Bicycle Brand</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="d2e14"/>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>Harley Davidson</Name>
         <StoreContact contactId="d1e38"/>
      </Product>
   </Products>
</ProductList>
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave you an upvote because it might be useful to somebody, but the schema (which I don't have control over) requires the id to be an integer.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, but I'm kind of hoping for a better one.  I will be running this with a .bat file, so I can use the XSLT to recreate itself but append the lookup table to the bottom, then I can use the batch file to run the new XSLT with the lookup table contained within and use the id's that are already assigned.  Does this sound like a possible solution (I believe I have seen ways to use XSLT to recreate itself and lookup tables within itself)?

Comment: The ids actually *are* integers. Would converting them from hex to decimal solve the problem?

Comment: That sounds like a better solution than mine

Comment: I should be able to use your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22905134/convert-a-hexadecimal-number-to-an-integer-in-xslt to figure this out.  Thanks.

Comment: If you can run a pipe, I would suggest using two (or more) *fixed* XSLT stylesheets in series, each operating on the output of another.