# How to group xml using attribute after storing multiple xml files in a variabel using XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

**File1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="base.xsl" ?>
<ROOT>
 <DATA SOURCE="Machine1" >
   <Details STATUS="A"/>
 </DATA>
 <DATA SOURCE="Machine2" >
   <Details STATUS="A"/>
 </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

---

**File2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ROOT>
 <DATA SOURCE="Machine1" >
   <Details STATUS="B"/>
 </DATA>
 <DATA SOURCE="Machine3" >
   <Details STATUS="A"/>
 </DATA>
</ROOT>
```

---

**Base.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet []>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transform"/>

    <xsl:variable name="allContents" select="(/ | document('File2.xml'))//DATA" />

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>Something Title</title>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                    <div class="title">
                        Something Title
                    </div>

                    <form>

                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$allContents" group-by="@SOURCE">
                            <div onclick="show(this);" style="cursor:hand">
                                <a href="#details">
                                    Machine: <b><xsl:value-of select="@SOURCE"/></b>
                                </a>


                                    <table>
                                        <tr class="title">
                                            <td class="borderless">
                                                <b>Number of Details:</b> <xsl:value-of select="count(Details/@STATUS)"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <table id="some" style="display:none">
                                    <div class="titlesub">
                                        Machine (Detail)
                                        <b><xsl:value-of select="@SOURCE"/></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="borderless">
                                            <a href="#topheader">Back To Top</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>Number of Files: </b>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Details/@STATUS)"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Status</th>

                                    </tr>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="Details">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text"><xsl:value-of select="@Status"/></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td> 
                                        <td class="borderless">
                                            <a href="#topheader"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>



                    </form>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Revised Base.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet []>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transform"/>

    <xsl:variable name="allContents" select="(/ | document('File2.xml'))//DATA" />
    <xsl:key match="DATA" name="data-by-machine" use="@SOURCE"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
            <title>Something Title</title>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                    <div class="title">
                        Something Title
                    </div>

                    <form>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$allContents[generate-id()=generate-id(key('data-by-machine',@SOURCE)[1])]">
                            <div onclick="show(this);" style="cursor:hand">
                                <a href="#details">
                                    Machine: <b><xsl:value-of select="@SOURCE"/></b>
                                </a>


                                    <table>
                                        <tr class="title">
                                            <td class="borderless">
                                                <b>Number of Details:</b> <xsl:value-of select="count(Details/@STATUS)"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <table id="some" style="display:none">
                                    <div class="titlesub">
                                        Machine (Detail)
                                        <b><xsl:value-of select="@SOURCE"/></b>
                                    </div>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td class="borderless">
                                            <a href="#topheader">Back To Top</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <div>
                                            <b>Number of Files: </b>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="count(Details/@STATUS)"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Status</th>

                                    </tr>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="Details">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="text"><xsl:value-of select="@STATUS"/></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td> 
                                        <td class="borderless">
                                            <a href="#topheader"></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <hr/>
                        </xsl:for-each>



                    </form>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

`File1.xml` and `File2.xml` are from different machines. What I wanted to do is to combine the contents of the two files in a single html output. I was able to combine the two files using the select statement in the xslt above. However, I wanted to group the elements by the SOURCE attribute of DATA element. I don't know why Machine1 with STATUS="A" and STATUS="B" still have different Machine1. Looking forward for your reply. I get stymied with what I am doing. The two files are automatically generated from the two machines.

I have revised my xsl to implement Muenchian grouping but I can't understand why I am still having a duplicate Machine1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954663/xslt-ignore-duplicate-elements-across-multiple-files/18958901 for a similar question with two different solutions, one first merging both files into a result tree fragment, converting it to a node set to then apply Muenchian grouping, the other using variables.

Comment: How can I select the allContents variable that store my data from File1 and File2 and do the grouping?Thanks.

Comment: If you want to show us your XSLT efforts then that is fine, but please do edit the question and show minimal but complete and well formatted code snippets instead of putting code into comments. Your attempt, assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor, with `for-each-group` looks fine but of course if you have two documents in that variable then you would need `<xsl:for-each-group select="$allContents" group-by="@SOURCE">`

Comment: Thank you Martin for the reply. I just deleted the previous and I think it's really better if I will show the complete snippets.

Comment: You have posted an XSLT sample but you have not told us which output you want respectively what is wrong with what you have. I mainly think, that inside of the `for-each-group`, you want, at least at some places, make sure you process/output values of all items in the group with e.g. `<b>Number of Details:</b> <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()/Details/@STATUS)"/>`. You current code nowhere uses `current-group()` and that way only outputs values of the first item in each group. There is also the issue that the input sample have `STATUS` attributes and your code selects `Status`.

Comment: Hi Martin, You are right. What I am lacking is the current-group(). I have added that and it works well now. This is the output and this is how I expected it to be.  Again, thank you so much. I am new to xslt.

Something Title 

 Machine: Machine1 
Number of Details:2  

Machine (Detail) Machine1
Number of Files: 2
------------
 Machine: Machine2 
Number of Details:1  

Machine (Detail) Machine2
Number of Files: 1
------------
 Machine: Machine3 
Number of Details:1
  
Machine (Detail) Machine3
Number of Files: 1

Comment: Just one more question. How can I implement this using Muenchian? Thanks.

Comment: I need to revised it and use Muenchian method instead because if run directly thru xml file, no output was provided. Thanks.

Comment: I discovered that having SOURCE="Machine1" from different files generate different ids. Is there a way to make them generate the same id?Can anybody reply please?Thank you.

Comment: I need also to get the current xml filename being executed to be used for look-up with the same filename from other machine. I am going crazy.