# Converting mutiple xml elements into single complex xml element

Tags: xslt

Converting mutiple xml elements into single complex xml element.

I would like to group child elements into one complex xml using parent value.

In the example given , source xml contains two xml records  for AUDIT_ID=1.

Based on the AUDIT_ID value can we combine two  into single  as given in the target xml using xslt?

Source xml:

```
<Header>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>1</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI_ID>100</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>AB</ESI_NAME>
</Audit_records>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>1</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI_ID>101</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>BC</ESI_NAME>
</Audit_records>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>2</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI_ID>103</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>TH</ESI_NAME>
</Audit_records>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>2</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI_ID>104</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>UI</ESI_NAME>
</Audit_records>
</Header>
```

Target Xml:

```
<Header>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>1</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI>
<ESI_ID>100</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>AB</ESI_NAME>
</ESI>
<ESI>
<ESI_ID>101</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>BC</ESI_NAME>
</ESI>
</Audit_records>
<Audit_records>
<AUDIT_ID>2</AUDIT_ID>
<ESI>
<ESI_ID>103</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>TH</ESI_NAME>
</ESI>
<ESI>
<ESI_ID>104</ESI_ID>
<ESI_NAME>UI</ESI_NAME>
</ESI>
</Audit_records>
</Header>
```

xslt used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
                xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/getrecord"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                  xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ATAS_BPEL">
<!--<xsl:key name="myaudit" match="/ns0:getrecordOutputCollection/ns0:getrecordOutput" use="/ns0:getrecordOutputCollection/ns0:getrecordOutput/ns0:AUDIT_ID"/> -->
  <xsl:key match="Audit_records" name="myaudit" use="AUDIT_ID"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns1:Header>
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:Header/ns0:Audit_records[generate-id() = generate-id(key('myaudit',AUDIT_ID)[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="AUDIT_ID" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
        <ns1:CARF>
          <ns1:Header>
            <ns1:AUDIT_ID>
              <xsl:value-of select="ns0:AUDIT_ID"/>
            </ns1:AUDIT_ID>
            <ns1:ESI >
                <ns1:ESI_ID>
                  <xsl:value-of select="key('myaudit',AUDIT_ID)/ns0:ESI_ID"/>
                </ns1:ESI_ID>
                <ns1:ESI_NAME>
                  <xsl:value-of select="key('myaudit',AUDIT_ID)/ns0:ESI_NAME"/>
                </ns1:ESI_NAME>
            </ns1:ESI>
          </ns1:Header>
        </ns1:CARF>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ns1:AUDITRECORDS>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: am using oracle jdev tool for xslt transformation . In current jdev vresion  xslt , xsl:key or xsl:for-each-group is not supported. is there any other simple ways to achive this ?

Comment: If `xsl:key` is not supported, then you're not using XSLT and I don't know what will work for you and what will not.

Comment: Perhaps you can use this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18958901/3016153

Comment: i have snippet of xslt which am using . But not getting exected response. Could you please help

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XSLT is using namespaces, but your sample input/desired output does not.

Here's something that should get you started, but you'll have to modify it for whatever namespaces are in your actual data...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="records" match="Audit_records" use="AUDIT_ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Header">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="Audit_records[generate-id()=generate-id(key('records',AUDIT_ID)[1])]">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|AUDIT_ID"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('records',AUDIT_ID)">
            <ESI>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::AUDIT_ID)]"/>
            </ESI>            
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsz/1

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you please let me know what does below code will do <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

Comment: @AjayShetty - That's the [identity transform](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#copying). It basically copies everything that isn't processed by another template as-is.

Comment: thanks @Daniel haley . I have just updated the source , target and xslt am using . Not sure issue is with name space or logic am using in xslt. could you please help

Comment: @AjayShetty - Changing the examples in your question invalidates the rest of the question and also this answer. Next time create a new question. You can always include a link to a previous question in the new question. I'm going to revert your changes so the question and answer still make sense. Here's an updated fiddle that uses your new input and desired output: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzknsz/2 If you still have issues please create a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel . It is really helpful . Sure if i have further changes , will create a new post .