# Counting duplicate node values with XSLT

Tags: xslt, duplicates, counting

I'm having trouble with a very basic XSLT task, and would be enormously grateful to anyone who would take pity on me and help.

I need to collate the values of every instance of a particular node into a table, and

My source XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="graball3.xsl"?>
<collection>
 <letter id="1">
  <textString>Lorem
   <textString>ipsum</textString>
   <textString>dolor sit</textString>
   <textString>amet</textString>
   consectetur adipiscing.
  </textString>
 </letter>
 <letter id="2">
  <textString>Et amo
   <textString>ipsum</textString>
   <textString>amet</textString>
  dolor sit.
  </textString>
 </letter>
</collection>
```

I want to output a table that gives the value of every instance of a  node, including nested ones. Where the value of two nodes is the same, I want to have one entry with a count beside it instead of two lines.

So the output would tell me the following:

```
<table>
<tr><td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing.</td><td>[1]</td></tr>
<tr><td>ispum </td><td>[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>dolor sit </td><td>[1]</td></tr>
<tr><td>amet</td><td>[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td>Et amo ipsum dolor sit. </td><td>[1]</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've tried to work out how to do this reading about Muenchain methods. And I thought this thread might be it:

[XSLT Ignore duplicate elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897691/xslt-ignore-duplicate-elements)

But that's only outputting the first instance of the node for me (albeit with an accurate count.)

Here's my code at the moment, copied from there.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="kString" match="letter" use="//textString"/>
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="main">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Content</th>
      <th>Count</th>
     </tr>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="collection"/>
   </table>
  </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="collection">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="letter[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kString', //textString)[1])]" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="letter" mode="group">
   <xsl:for-each select=".">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="//textString"/>
     </td>
     <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kString', //textString))"/>
     </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'd be so grateful for any help.

Comment: You are referencing `letter` where you should be referencing `textString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kString" match="textString" use="."/>

<xsl:template match="/collection">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Content</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="letter//textString[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kString', .)[1])]">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count(key('kString', .))"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```